# To include the KISS Grammar site to "Resources for learning English"

Tags: discussion, online-resources

I've just found out about this great website, **[the KISS Grammar site](http://www.kissgrammar.org/)**. In my humble opinion, it could be a great resource for ELLs, even though it seems to aim toward native English-speaking children in America.

But before hasting to add that to ELL's resource page, I would like to hear your opinions first. (I'm not sure about its correctness, but from what I read in American teacher discussion threads, it seems to be a great resource for their classes.)

Comment: Go for it! If it helped you as a learner, maybe it will help others - and that's what our resource list is all about!

Comment: It looks like a somewhat idiosyncratic site to me. Take this (Victorian?) translation from Aesop's Fables... [A Grasshopper, perishing with famine, passed by and earnestly begged for a little food. The Ants inquired of him, “Why did you not treasure up food during the summer?” He replied, “I had not leisure enough”](http://www.kissgrammar.org/KISS_Dif.htm). Nobody speaks or writes like that today, so why on earth would the KISS site choose it as an example to illustrate how well their approach to grammar works? In short, I do ***not*** endorse it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not going to argue that. I just would like to know which kind of literature native English-speaking children learn before the college level. Back in my school days, I still remember that in my first language classes, I had to study very old ancient texts that are very different from the current usage (at that time, as can be found in news, books, magazines, TV, and so on).

Comment: @Damkerng: From my own knowledge of UK practice, I don't think many mainstream English teachers would want to stray too far from "current" texts (certainly less than 50 years old) in the context of teaching *language* itself. You'd only really want to introduce things like Shakespeare (or even Dickens) when you're teaching *literature* to older students.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much for the information.